# Form doesn't work after publishing website but it's work on localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

my project work on localhost and will submit form and hit the action but it in the iis server, form will submit and 404 result will back to user.

[image: My Form]

[image: My Controller]

[image: And My Browser Result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to my web.config and change the value of the stdLogEnabled to true and create a log folder in root of project and found the exception that made this for me.

Answer (score 0):

I see in one of the pages you are on HTTP and in another on HTTP
do you have HttpsRedirection enabled in Startup.cs?
I didn't know much from your question but I guess your problem is because of https redirection.
just remove the line which redirects to HTTPS and try again.

remove this

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

Comment: it doesn't worked for me and i never use https in my project